# How to save multiple row from a form in laravel 5 Controller

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a function in controller where multiple row from a form is being saved it looks like this ,

```
  public function postPayment(PaymentRequest $request){

                $insertPayment=Input::get();

                $payment= new paymentrecieved();

                $data=array();

          for($i = 0; $i < count($insertPayment['recieved_amount']); $i++) {

                if($insertPayment['adjustmentmode'][$i]=='Option')
                $adjust_mode='NONE';
                else
                  $adjust_mode=$insertPayment['adjustmentmode'][$i];

                $payment->invoice_id=$insertPayment['invoiceid'];
                $payment->recieved_amount = $insertPayment['recieved_amount'][$i];
                $payment->refno = $insertPayment['ref_no'][$i];
                $payment->date = $insertPayment['date'][$i];
                $payment->adjust_amount = $insertPayment['adjustmentamount'][$i];
                $payment->adjust_mode= $adjust_mode;
                $payment->save();


         }

         // $result = paymentrecieved::create($data);
          $this->saveComment($insertPayment['comment'],$insertPayment['date1'],$insertPayment['invoiceid']);
          $request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'Payment Has Been inserted Successfully');
          return redirect('collection/payment/'.$insertPayment['invoiceid'].'');

    }
```

So in the loop I am trying to save multiple row , But only the last row of the form is being saved i n my database . Any leads on what could be the issue .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer fix is here

```
public function postPayment(PaymentRequest $request){

                $insertPayment=Input::get();

                $data=array();

          for($i = 0; $i < count($insertPayment['recieved_amount']); $i++) {

                $payment= new paymentrecieved();
                if($insertPayment['adjustmentmode'][$i]=='Option')
                $adjust_mode='NONE';
                else
                  $adjust_mode=$insertPayment['adjustmentmode'][$i];

                $payment->invoice_id=$insertPayment['invoiceid'];
                $payment->recieved_amount = $insertPayment['recieved_amount'][$i];
                $payment->refno = $insertPayment['ref_no'][$i];
                $payment->date = $insertPayment['date'][$i];
                $payment->adjust_amount = $insertPayment['adjustmentamount'][$i];
                $payment->adjust_mode= $adjust_mode;
                $payment->save();


         }

         // $result = paymentrecieved::create($data);
          $this->saveComment($insertPayment['comment'],$insertPayment['date1'],$insertPayment['invoiceid']);
          $request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'Payment Has Been inserted Successfully');
          return redirect('collection/payment/'.$insertPayment['invoiceid'].'');

    }
```